# Pass a bitmap object to Interop Word function that is expecting a filename string for a bitmap file

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, ms-word, vsto

The title sounds insane but bear with me. This is a problem that could exist with any object.

I am generating a bitmap object in memory and I would like to pass it directly to another function that wants to open a bitmap file. The simple solution is to write the file to disk, call the function against the file, and then delete the file. I don't want to do that. If I am pushing a high volume of image objects in to a Word document with a VSTO add-in it doesn't make sense to thrash my disk for no reason when the whole thing could be done in memory.

I guess I am looking for a different function to insert a picture in to a Word document that accepts a bitmap object. Or a way to pass a filesystem object that actually points to memory (Not a RAMDisk, but a RAMFile?). Or a way to wire the "Image.Save" directly to the reader of the "AddPicture" function without actually making a file on disk.

Hopefully, there is a better way of doing this.

Here is the code example:

```
Dim newImage = GenerateImage(InputString, SelectedFormat)
Dim imagePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName())
newImage.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png)

With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    .Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath)
End With

File.Delete(imagePath)
```

Comment: Your choices are basically: 1) The Clipboard and 2) wrapping the bitmap in valid, OPC flat-file format Word Open XML, which means first converting the bitmap to base64. For the first, use the Paste or PasteSpecial method in Word to insert it. For the second, Word's Range.InsertXML method.

Comment: Word doesn't handle images well once they reach a certain resolution/filesize so your images must be a reasonable size. Since that is the case, disk I/O shouldn't be all that significant. Even if they are ~3MB (around here is where Word starts having trouble iirc), hard disks can easily handle that kind of activity with no real threat to longevity. If you use Cindy's suggestion though, [you'll need this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/29/transforming-flat-opc-format-to-open-xml-documents/). @CindyMeister put it in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word can't "stream" (see "Background", below) content, so your choices are 1) The Clipboard or 2) wrapping the bitmap in valid, Word Open XML OPC flat-file format, which means first converting the bitmap to base64.

For the first, you can use standard .NET methods to place the information on the Clipboard in the format you want Word to use. In the Word "interop", the Paste or PasteSpecial methods will insert it. The argument against this approach is, as ever, "interfering" with the user's Clipboard.

Using Word Open XML is as close as you can get to "streaming" content into Word, using the `Range.InsertXML` method.

Word documents (and other Office files) are essentially "zip packages" of XML and binary files that together make up the document. It's possible to create and edit these files without opening them in the Word (Office) application, which makes the format suitable for server-side work. Any tool that can work with zip files and xml can be used for this; standard is the Microsoft Open XML SDK which offers a complete API of the Office content.

Word, alone, of all the Office applications enables the developer to read and write content in the *opened* Word document using the OPC flat-file standard. This "concatenates" the entire content of the zip package into an XML String. The Word object model's `Range.InsertXML` method is used to write content in this format to a Word document open in the Word application.

Information on how to convert a zip package into OPC flat file can be found in this [blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/29/transforming-flat-opc-format-to-open-xml-documents/). Information concerning minimal Word Open XML to have a valid OPC version is described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml); there is a section in there specifically about working with graphics.

**Background**

Word is based on very old technology - late 1980's. By the mid-1990's it reached a very high standard as a professional word processor and what has happened with it since has mostly been "sugar coating" - adding a bit of this and a bit of that to bring it closer to HTML / page layouting. But the core of the application remains the same... and part of that means Word isn't able to do many of the things the modern developer expects - such as "streaming" data in and out.

Comment: The clipboard is the thing I was describing. User be damned. Thanks Cindy. I don't know why I didn't think of copy\paste right away. I guess I avoid those functions so much I forgot I could.